# Failed to exploit netapi vulnerability on Windows server 2003 R2

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, windows-server

I am trying to exploit the ms08_0067_netapi vulnerability on windows server 2003 R2 but the exploitation end with the following message:

Exploit completed, but no session was created.

Any thoughts?

Screenshot"
[image]

Comment: nmap -p 445 -script smb-check-vulns -script-args=unsafe=1 <IP Address>  <--- does nmap show the service as active and vulnerabile on the remote host?

Do you know that the language pack for the target is in fact English?

Comment: Host script results:
| smb-vuln-ms08-067: 
|   VULNERABLE:
|   Microsoft Windows system vulnerable to remote code execution (MS08-067)
|     State: VULNERABLE
|     IDs:  CVE:CVE-2008-4250
|           The Server service in Microsoft Windows 2000 SP4, XP SP2 and SP3, Server 2003 SP1 and SP2,
|           Vista Gold and SP1, Server 2008, and 7 Pre-Beta allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary
|           code via a crafted RPC request that triggers the overflow during path canonicalization.
|           
|     Disclosure date: 2008-10-23

Comment: Are you confident that English is the correct language pack for this remote host?

Comment: Yes sir @DarkMatter